# How to get a Bearer access token for Service Accounts

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token, service-accounts, bearer-token

I have generate credentials for a service account like this:

```
f = file(settings.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH, 'rb')
key = f.read()
f.close()
credentials = client.SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(settings.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL, key, scope=settings.GROUPS_SCOPE, sub=settings.ADMIN_DOMAIN_EMAIL)
print 'credentials : '+str(credentials.to_json())
```

the print display the credentials in json format :

```
{"private_key": "MIIGwAIBAzCCBnoGLUn09Ywa1l7G8XC2SgA9eDhXAdKw4DAh...83J+6iAgIEAA==", "id_token": null, "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", "token_response": null, "client_id": null, "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group", "token_expiry": null, "_class": "SignedJwtAssertionCredentials", "refresh_token": null, "_module": "oauth2client.client", "private_key_password": "notasecret", "access_token": null, "service_account_name": "xxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com", "invalid": false, "assertion_type": null, "kwargs": {"sub": "username@domain.com"}, "client_secret": null, "revoke_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke", "user_agent": null}
```

This generate a private key ans access token that is null.

Is there a class that handels REST request specified [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount#creatingjwt) to get the access token ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `access_token = credentials.get_access_token()`
 https://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/oauth2client.client.html#oauth2client.client.OAuth2Credentials.get_access_token